# Drop and re-create index in ServiceStack OrmLite

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I have some MSSQL tables created by ServiceStack.OrmLite and I'd like to programmatically change the types of some some columns or perhaps drop and re-create some of them (with different types). The problem is that some of them may be used in indexes (also created by OrmLite from [Index]/[CompositeIndex] attributes). Is there an easy way to ask OrmLite to drop and to create all indexes used by particular column?

I noticed there is IDbConnection.CreateIndex, but this probably won't work for composite indexes. There is also IDbConnection.DropIndex, but that requires the name of the index, which I don't have.

Answer (score 2):

There's no API that says "drop/re-create Indexes for a column", the only DDL APIs OrmLite offers are on the [OrmLiteSchemaModifyApi](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.OrmLite/OrmLiteSchemaModifyApi.cs) class.

You'll need to use [db.ExecuteSql](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#custom-insert-and-updates) for any other table modifications you want to perform programmatically.

Comment: OK, thanks. Would you be open to a PR that implemented something like this? I envision the API as: a method to drop the index for a column and method to drop/create all indexes that use specified columns (including composite indexes). Maybe methods to drop/create all indexes would be helpful, too - that would just be exposing existing functionality used by CreateTable.

Comment: @EM0 we'd be open to a PR it'd just need to be intuitive to use and non disruptive to existing code base